# Resharper External Attributes with MSTest's [DeploymentItem]

Tags: c#, resharper, mstest

In certain cases (like when writing URIs in XAML), ReSharper magically figures out I am writing out a relative path to a file in the current project and offers very useful smart-completion for it, and a warning if I misspell something and get it wrong, and even goes to the file if I ctrl+click it.

Can I somehow tell ReSharper to do the same when I'm typing in the parameter to MSTest's [DeploymentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.common.deploymentitem.aspx) attribute?

Comment: Don't think ReSharper supports this feature

Comment: It is not possible in ReSharper right now. However I filed a new feature request http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-420839

Answer (score 1):

This *should* work through an [external annotation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html).  Open the following file:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v7.1\Bin\ExternalAnnotations\Visual Studio\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.xml

(Or whatever version of Resharper you're using.)

Add these lines inside the `assembly` tag:

```xml
<member name="M:Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.DeploymentItemAttribute.#ctor(System.String)">
    <parameter name="path">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.PathReferenceAttribute.#ctor" />
    </parameter>
</member>
<member name="M:Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.DeploymentItemAttribute.#ctor(System.String,System.String)">
    <parameter name="path">
        <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.PathReferenceAttribute.#ctor" />
    </parameter>
</member>
```

That tells Resharper to throw the [`PathReference`](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#PathReferenceAttribute) attribute on the `path` parameter of both constructors of `DeploymentItem`.

*However*, after testing for some time now I cannot see this attribute working on anything that I try within the C# text editor.  It could be that it doesn't work for my version (7.1), but I'm a bit stumped.  Perhaps someone can add to this?

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but [according to Alexander from JetBrains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219556/resharper-external-attributes-with-mstests-deploymentitem#comment39356514_25219556), this is not currently possible